# admob for version 1.6

Tags: android, admob

I have a admob project that works great when the android version in project properties is set to 2.3. But When I try to set on 1.6 then it complaints in the android manifest at this lines

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd guess that you need to check which tags are supported in that SDK version.

See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config).

See that uiMode was added in SDK 8 and screenSize in 13. Try that.

Here it works even in 1.5. Just an example:

```
    <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"
        />
```

Comment: That is the line I use in 1.5. That's what I mean. Which error message you get? Where?

Comment: But the SDK still requiring configChanges screenLayout, uiMode, screenSize, smallestScreenSize and ads doesn't shows.


02-10 22:10:20.692: E/Ads(1887): You must have AdActivity declared in AndroidManifest.xml with configChanges.

Comment: @PoisoneR : Compile with a higher SDK then. Don't use exclusive features from that version and you'll be fine regarding backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

That is because most of those values in the `configChanges` attribute were introduced in SDKs after Android 1.6, so to get rid of that error you have to compile against SDK 13 (Android 3.2) -- install the SDK, and in your project Properties / Android / Project Build Target make sure it's Android 3.2.

In addition, if you want to target older devices (earlier than 3.2), make sure you keep `minSdkVersion="4"` so the users of Android 1.6 and up could install your app too.