# Admob ads not displayed on android 1.6

Tags: android, admob, android-1.6-donut

i have an app that runs perfectly on android 1.6+, but admob ads are not displayed only in 1.6 version.

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"  
      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

Project build target: android 3.2

I've tried many options without any success.

Comment: This might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187159/admob-for-version-1-6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will displayed, but somehow does not get result from server, you can check Ad retrieving process from log:

```
adb logcat
```

Comment: 04-01 17:48:02.001: I/Ads(997): onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad request successful, but no ad returned due to lack of ad inventory.) But on android 2.1 emulator shows ads. Maybe there is no ads available for android 1.6.

Comment: yup, no problem with your code. it will displayed, when there is ad for your app